# How do I use the dot syntax in Julia function calls

Tags: vectorization, julia

According to [Julia documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/functions/#dot-syntax-for-vectorizing-functions), I should be able to call a given (even non-vectorized) function for every element in an array using `fun.(A)`, where `A` is an array. I try with a simple example and it doesn't seem to work:

```
julia> x = collect(linspace(0,pi,100));
julia> y = sin.(x)
ERROR: TypeError: getfield: expected Symbol, got Array{Float64,1}
```

The same error persists with all my own functions. How do I use this feature correctly?

Comment: Are you on v0.5 or higher? What's your `versioninfo()`?

Comment: It says 0.4.7. Does this mean I should upgrade to newer version of Julia to use this feature?

Comment: Yes v0.5 or newer  for broadcasting function calls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to give this an official answer, this is a new feature that was introduced in Julia 0.5, while @Echows was using Julia 0.4. The solution is to upgrade to Julia 0.5 or newer.